# Can I upload directly to Amazon S3 bucket using PHP without saving it in loc al system?

Tags: php, html, amazon-web-services, post, amazon-s3

I am taking the input of a file using multipart form data using a post form over the cloud. Can I be able to upload it directly to the Amazon S3 Bucket without saving it on the local system? I tried it by saving on the local system and then uploading it to the s3 Bucket. It worked fine but I want to know that can it be uploaded directly using the post form without saving it to the local system.

Answer (score 2):

it could probably be done with stream wrapper of the S3 SDK. Read in chunks from php://input and write to s3, however, php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".

But why not upload to your S3 bucket directly from the client using a [presigned POST URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-presigned-post.html)?

Comment: I have few validation checks in the file that I am uploading actually. I used to save in local server when I was just coding in my apache in my own laptop but when I moved my service to amazon ec2 saving in the instance itself was a tedious job to do. So now I need to use the s3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed with you logic and after uploading to s3 you can simply unlink the file from you local enviroment folder